# system libraries for tracing?

Tags: c, linux

Here's the problem:

I have a file on a server, which needs to have a certain set of permissions, say 644. From time to time some process changes the permissions to 600, and I don't know which. How do I catch it in the act?

For this sort of problems and other similar ones, I am looking for a set of system libraries (I think) which I can insert in front of the normal ones, which do pretty much the same as the normal libraries, except that they in some way log the calls made along with timestamp and the name of the perpetrator. Are there any tools - libraries, whatever - that provide this?

Comment: What have you considered? Have you looked into `strace`? `gdb`? `selinux`?

Comment: You could possibly write your own and use [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) to monitor the file. And write your own you probably have to, because if you don't know what program is actually changing the file permissions you can't really do anything.

Comment: You could also try and identify the process modifying the permissions, if the process keeps the file open, with the [`lsof`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html) command.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to identify by which program this is being changed. To do that you could use SElinux, some linux distribution (if not all) have it's setting in the `/etc/selinux` where you can define rules for what's allowed. Violations for the rules will be denied, but also failed attempts will be logged (so this both gets rid of the symptoms as well as point to the cause).

For more information about SElinux I'd suggest you ask on Unix/Linux exchange.

Next step if it's your own program would probably be to run it under `gdb` and put a conditional breakpoint at the `chmod` function. You also have functionality in `gdb` just to do a printout from the breakpoint and continue which would allow the program to run almost normally, but get printouts for every file that is `chmod`ed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing auditing was designed to do.

See [How can I audit all chmod and chgrp commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438016/how-can-i-audit-all-chmod-and-chgrp-commands) for an example that probably qualifies as a duplicate of your question.